# Client id of elements changes in sharepoint page? Why? When?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Client id of every element from the sharepoint page changes sometimes.
Can anybody please tell me why and on which instance it changes???

Comment: Check this [question][1] and you will get some ideas.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325687/sharepoint-textfield-clientid-changes

Comment: I've found in my experiences that it's always best to assume that the ClientIDs are entirely dynamic and I never every rely on them to be anything that they were before.  It's not actually that hard to do in my experiences.  If you would like help solving a problem without hard coding a ClientID, I'd be glad to help with it.

Answer (score 2):

> jQuery is fantastic! It makes client-side development faster and
>   countless plug-ins are available for just about every need. Using
>   jQuery with Asp.NET Web-Forms gets aggravating when dealing with
>   nested server controls. ClientID’s get appended when using ASP.NET
>   Master Pages. Objects in JavaScript tend to look like this:
>       ctl00_m_g_aaf13d41_fc78_40be_81d5_2f40e534844f_txtName
>       The difficulty of the issue above is that, in order to get the element txtName, It’s necessary to know the full “path”. It’s quite
>   aggravating to refer to get the object using the method below:
>       document.getElementByID('ctl00_m_g_aaf13d41_fc78_40be_81d5_2f40e534844f_txtName');
>       This becomes a big problem when developing server controls or web parts that may be used in a typical ASP.NET application or SharePoint.
>   You cannot hard-code the path above if you don’t know the full path of
>   the control.
>
> Fortunately, there are a few ways to get around this. There are three, in particular, I will mention. The first is the jQuery
>   equivalent to the standard JavaScript method:
>       document.getElementById("<%=txtName.ClinetID%>");");
>       This can be done in jQuery by using:
>       $("#'<%=txtName.ClinetID%>");");
>       The second jQuery method does not require server tags. This method searches through all tags and looks for an element ending with the
>   specified text. The jQuery code for this method is shown below:
>       $("[id$='_txtName']");
>       There are, of course, drawbacks to both methods above. The first is fast, but requires server tags. It’s fast, but it just looks messy.
>   Also, it will not work with external script files. The second
>   alternative is clean, but it can be slow. As I said earlier, there are
>   several other alternatives, but these two are the ones I find myself
>   using the most.
>
> The third registering Javascript in C# code behind.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "saveScript",

String.Format("function EnableSave( isDisabled )"+

"{{ var saveButton = document.getElementById(\"{0}\");"+

"saveButton.disabled=isDisabled;}}", btnSave.ClientID), true);
```

> Do not forget to call this script after controls have been loaded, I mean after Controls.Add(); in CreateChildControls method while
>   developing webparts.

Answer (score 0):

$('input[title="Name"]')

Look at the page source and get the value of the title property - works every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBox1.Attributes.Add("onmouseup",
    "document.getElementById('" + base.ClientID + "_" + lbnFilter.ClientID + "').style.display='block';");
```